# Apache NiFi: how to add logging for a specific processor

Tags: logging, apache-nifi

I added logging to *conf/logback.xml* for a *ValidateRecord* processor with this code:

```
<appender name="Validation" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>logs/ValidateRecord.log</file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
        <pattern>%date %level [%thread] %logger{40} %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

 <logger name="org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ValidateRecord" level="DEBUG">
<appender-ref ref="Validation" />
</logger>
```

Then I use TailFile processor to extract messages from *ValidateRecord.log* when given JSON file does not correspond with required JSON schema. But the problem is that all messages from all *ValidateRecord* processors go to this file and i don't want that.

What I need is to specify a logger for a specific process group or for a specific *ValidateRecord* processor. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: not sure it's possible to do unless you'll find something unique to those log records and [filter](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html) them.

Comment: @daggett Any ideas where I can write this filter?

Answer (score 0):

> What I need is to specify a logger for a specific process group or for
>   a specific ValidateRecord processor. Is there a way to do it?

Not yet. It would require a bit of work to make each instance of a processor register a unique `Logger` object.